# don't understand these directions - ssl

Tags: x509certificate, digital-signature, private-key, public-key

I was sent these directions: Export the Public Key (.p7b or .cer) and the Private Key (.pfx) from the certificate. Set a password for your Private Key (.pfx).Use your private key as your signing certificate. When you send a submission you will be prompted to enter in your signing certificate password, this will be the password you set for your Private Key (.pfx).. After you have exported both files successfully, send us a copy of your new Public Key (.p7b or .cer) to: []

I understand that .p7b or .cer  and .pfx would have the certificate included. So -- are they calling the public key plus the certificate, and the private key plus certificate, "public key" and "private key"?

Is this the usual way this is done?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly does this question have to do with SSL?

Answer (score 0):

> I was sent these directions:

Hmm, let's see.

> Export the Public Key (.p7b or .cer) and the Private Key (.pfx) from the certificate.

Impossible. The private key isn't *in* the certificate. And there is no reason to export the public key. It's of no use without the certificate.

> Set a password for your Private Key (.pfx).

Good.

> Use your private key as your signing certificate.

This is completed and utter nonsense. A private key cannot be used as a certificate. It isn't a certificate. [It can however be used to *sign* things: if that's what they're talking about they should have said so, clearly.]

> When you send a submission you will be prompted to enter in your signing certificate password, this will be the password you set for your Private Key (.pfx).

More nonsense, see above.

> After you have exported both files successfully, send us a copy of your new Public Key (.p7b or .cer) to: []

Yet more nonsense. Sending the public key accomplishes nothing, and a .cer file isn't a key file, it's a certificate file.

> I understand that .p7b or .cer  and .pfx would have the certificate included. So -- are they calling the public key plus the certificate, and the private key plus certificate, "public key" and "private key"?

They are talking rank nonsense. If those are really the directions you were sent, tell them so, send them back, get your money back, and start all over again with somebody that actually knows what they're talking about. These instructions cannot possibly have been even tested.

> Is this the usual way this is done?

It is drivel.

But what exactly is 'this' that is supposed to be getting done here?

Comment: I created a self signed certificate. They are not a CA.

Comment: So who *are* 'they', and what exactly is 'this' that is supposed to be getting done here?

Comment: It seems that windows and internet explorer actually do function like that. I was able to export what was being called a "public" and "private" key from a .pfx certificate (i.e.>tools>content>certificates) into a .cer or .p7b for the "public" and .pfx for the "private" key.

Comment: This is an organization using the Axway gateway to send and receive communications.

Answer (score -2):

Certificate is structure which includes the public key plus additional info (owner/domain,possible use,expiration date,issuer,etc.).

Comment: Correct, but you haven't really answered the question.